# Is it possible to group by on a constant column in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am running a Hive query as below with group by on standard non-aggregate table columns key1 and key2. But I am adding a constant type column based on where condition to each table being union-ed.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T_FINAL AS SELECT DISTINCT union_tbles.key1 AS key1, union_tbles.key2 AS key2, union_tbles.cnt AS cnt, union_tbles.type AS type FROM (
SELECT key1 AS key1, key2 AS key2, COUNT(val) AS cnt, 'x1' AS type FROM T_SUB1 WHERE key1 IN ('X1') GROUP BY key1, key2
UNION ALL
SELECT key1 AS key1, key2 AS key2, COUNT(val) AS cnt, 'x2' AS type FROM T_SUB1 WHERE key1 IN ('X2') GROUP BY key1, key2
) union_tbles
```

Is it possible to add the constant column type asa group-by column as below?
When I am trying to add the constant column type in group-by, I am getting Invalid column alias error in Hive. Any suggestion how to do it in Hive?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T_FINAL AS SELECT DISTINCT union_tbles.key1 AS key1, union_tbles.key2 AS key2, union_tbles.cnt AS cnt, union_tbles.type AS type FROM (
SELECT key1 AS key1, key2 AS key2, COUNT(val) AS cnt, 'x1' AS type FROM T_SUB1 WHERE key1 IN ('X1') GROUP BY key1, key2, type
UNION ALL
SELECT key1 AS key1, key2 AS key2, COUNT(val) AS cnt, 'x2' AS type FROM T_SUB1 WHERE key1 IN ('X2') GROUP BY key1, key2, type
) union_tbles
```

Comment: "SELECT DISTINCT"?

Comment: And why is the "UNION ALL" in the first place?

Comment: I am running a JOIN on a series of UNIONs. I ran that in two ways - SELECT DISTINCT ( ... UNION ALL ... UNION ALL ... etc )  and SELECT FROM ( ... UNION DISTINCT ... UNION DISTINCT ). In the first way, the number of jobs was 15 while in the second way, it was 25. Just adding UNION DISTINCT significantly increased the number of jobs. And each job is using 9068 mappers and 1009 reducers. So the time it is taking is exorbitantly high. So I wanted to cut down on the number of jobs.

Comment: But you don't need not the `distinct` (there cannot be duplicates after the group by) nor the `union all` in the first place. It can be written using a single `select`. You are trying to tune what is badly written from its base.

Comment: P.s. `select distinct from`? Aren't there some columns missing?

Comment: Yes I didn't mention that but there are columns after select distinct. I just meant the construct

Comment: 1. I already answered your question 2. I strongly suggest that you'll get assistant with your SQL. You can post a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not recognize aliases in the GROUP BY clause.
In any case there is absolute no need to group by constants.
Constant needn't be in the GROUP BY clause in order to selected.

```
with t as (select 1 as x)
select    x
         ,count(*)
         ,1+1
         ,'Hello'
         ,current_date()
from      t
group by  x
```

---

```
+---+-----+-----+-------+------------+
| x | _c1 | _c2 |  _c3  |    _c4     |
+---+-----+-----+-------+------------+
| 1 |   1 |   2 | Hello | 2017-04-17 |
+---+-----+-----+-------+------------+
```